# Using SymPy to find differential equation in new coordinate system (after rescaling)

Tags: python, math, sympy

In my work, a common task is to re-write differential equations in new coordinate systems (rescaling both the coordinates and the functions). As the calculations can get rather tedious, I would like to automate this with SymPy.

Below is a simplified example, which (hopefully) shows what I want to achieve. NOTE: I am *not* interested in trying to solve the ODE -- all I care about are the coefficients in the new coordinate system.

So, given the original ODE:

[image]

and the scaling relations:

[image]

and

[image]

I would like to use SymPy to get to the new ODE:

[image]

Below is some code with what I tried (without getting too far). If I

```py
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing(use_unicode=True)

# define symbols for original coordinate & constants
x, alpha, beta, gamma = sp.symbols('x alpha beta, gamma',
                                   real=True, positive=True)

# define symbol for original function
u = sp.Function('u', real=True)(x)

original_ode = sp.Eq(u.diff(x) + alpha, 0)
# define symbol for new coordinate
x_d = sp.symbols('x_d', real=True, positive=True)

# define symbol for new function (in the new coordinate system)
u_d = sp.Function('u_d', real=True)(x_d)

# define scaling relations (for transfer to x_d coordinate)
#x_d = x / beta
#u_d = u / gamma # u_d is the new function (int the new coordinate system)

# TODO: find out how to obtain the ODE for u_d(x_d)
expected_ode = sp.Eq(  # <-- I would like to derive this equation,
                       #     instead of writing it manually
    u_d.diff(x_d) + (alpha*beta)/gamma,
    0
)
expected_ode
```

Comment: Thank you @RoryDaulton for improving the look of the equations!